# Why when I'm sending emails with CDO in Classic ASP I get Ã± instead of ñ?

Tags: email, utf-8, asp-classic, cdo.message, iis-8.5

I'm having problems sending email in Classic ASP with CDO in IIS 8.5 and Windows 8.1, the problem happens with latin characters, like ñ áéíóúü etc. For Example if I put the ñ in the subject and/or in the body I get Ã±.

These is my code:

```
Set objConfig = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Fields = objConfig.Fields

With Fields
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")      = 2 
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")     = "smtp.gmail.com"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")   = "email@gmail.com"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")   = "the-pwd-123"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")     = true
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")   = 1

 .Update
End With

Set objMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig

With objMessage
 .BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"
 '.BodyPart.Charset = "unicode-1-1-utf-8"
 .To       = "<email@gmail.com>"
 .From     = "<email2@gmail.com>"
 .Subject  = "Envio de contraseña"
 .TextBody = "This email has a ñ to see how it looks when sending email through CDO"
 .Send
End With
```

The configuration of the email is UTF8, then where is the problem?, How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, try adding this to the top of your page

`<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>`.

Also, as your ñ is hardcoded,  save the file with UTF-8 encoding.  If you open it in Notepad (or just about any editor other than VS) and select Save As you should see an encoding dropdown in the dialogue box which appears.

See this for further information. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: In VS you customise the menu options by adding the `Advanced Save Options` menu item found in the `File` menu commands.

Comment: @Lankymart - which VS version is that, I couldn't find it on 2010? Though  I have now discovered the little down arrow icon on the right of the save button which offers a "Save with encoding" option.

Comment: All versions its not on the File menu by default you have to go into menu customisation and add it. Usually right click on the toolbar to bring up the Menu / Toolbar customise option.

Comment: I use Notepad++ and the file was saved as UTF-8 without BOM then I changed to just UTF-8 and problem solved. My Meta-tags were: <%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<% Session.LCID = 8202 %>